# Saving a none string date to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, postgresql

I am developing an Rails 5.2 and Angular 7 app and I am using the NG-bootstrap datepicker. The problem with this is that it gives me an object rather than a string with the selected date and Rails will not save that to the database (or even permit it in the controller).

This is the response sent to the server:

```
Parameters: {"title"=>"hello", "company_id"=>"", "starts_at_date"=>{"year"=>2019, "month"=>1, "day"=>4}, "due_at_date"=>{"year"=>2019, "month"=>1, "day"=>2}, "description"=>"A small description", "project"=>{"company_id"=>"", "title"=>"hello", "description"=>"A small descriptio"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

How can I allow the following object to be permitted in the controller AND save it to the database?

```
{"year"=>2019, "month"=>1, "day"=>4}
```

Thankful for all help!